# Is it must to point source files for jacoco report generation

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

I have created jacoco.exec file by setting -javaagent as jvm option in my server startup script. Now I want to generate coverage report using the coverage exec file.

I've gone though all Jacoco report generation options (maven, ant, API etc..) However all these options required to have source class files. I'm trying to generate coverage for set of jar files where as sources files are not available. In that case, is there a workaround to achieve coverage generation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, *why* do you want to generate a coverage report for classes with no sources? What is the end goal?

Comment: I'm trying to generate coverage for server side so only jar files are available. And you can assume these jar files are third party jars where I don't have source code. Still I need to generate coverage report by invoking sever side APIs though my test classes. Coverage numbers matters for me to generate metric and find out whether all server side APIs are covered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate report without source code, I also generated the exec file by setting the option in server startup script, then I got the exec file and generated the report in eclipse using eclemma code coverage plugin.